# How to disable a driver from reopening when connecting a device it recognizes?

Tags: kernel-modules

After doing `sudo rmmod usbhid` the `usbhid` driver only reopens when I connect a device, which I don't want because I want to write a custom driver for it and I need it disabled until I say otherwise. The driver itself is not dependant of any other, and it does not give me any errors when removing the module.

So, my question is, how can I disable a driver(in this case `usbhid`) until reboot or manual enable, not permanently, without the kernel reopening it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could leverage the blacklist functions of modprobe.d. Add the module to /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf, or add your custom load command, and then comment it out when you're ready to reboot.

https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Kernel_module#Blacklisting